# How to append a variable result into specific column in csv?

Tags: python, csv, logging

**Given:**

[sha1_vsdt.csv](https://pastebin.com/rvX2vZ8A)

```
SHA-1,VSDT,
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5,MIME 6010-0,
02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324,Microsoft RTF 6008-0,undet
```

[trendx.log](https://pastebin.com/0Yc6JVs5)

```
1537761898  0   1   1   1537733097  1537733098  1537733097  8224    74  215552  06a60c6018a42b1db22e3bf8620861711401c4bb.crdownload TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026 c:\users\administrator\desktop\downloader\download\     TRENDX  172.20.4.179    Administrator           c1f387a6f45414366755b0a1874b36ff9596d8ad        AABACACCBIiAgXWACAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=        TSPY_HPDYRE.SM;TSPY_GOLROTED.ACS;TROJ_GEN.R021C0FFO15;TROJ_GEN.R021C0DLO15;Ransom_HPCRYPTESLA.SM2;
```

**Task:**

My task is to match my strings in first column in sha1_vsdt.csv to my trendx.log file. Once it finds it matched it should get the description in log file and put it in the third column of csv, otherwise put undetected.

I already did the matching string and I get the results, but I don't know how to dump the results into the third column of csv. What should I use? Is there any library that I can use?

**Example:** If `0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5` find it match in log file get the description then put it in third column

```
SHA-1,VSDT,
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5,MIME 6010-0,
```

resul will be like this:

```
SHA-1,VSDT,DESC
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5,MIME 6010-0,TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026
```

**Code:** I can already get the results but I don't know how to dump the variable `result` into the third column of csv, please help

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
logtext = "trendx.log"
#Log data into dataframe using genfromtxt
logdata = np.genfromtxt(logtext + ".txt",invalid_raise = False,dtype=str, comments=None,usecols=np.arange(16))
logframe = pd.DataFrame(logdata)
#print (logframe.head())

#Dataframe trimmed to use only SHA1, PRG and IP
df2=(logframe[[10,11]]).rename(columns={10:'SHA-1', 11: 'DESC'})
#print (df2.head())

#sha1_vsdt data into dataframe using read_csv
df1=pd.read_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)
#Using merge to compare the two CSV

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SHA-1', how='left').fillna('undetected')
result = (df[['DESC']])
print result
```

**My Output:**

```
                              DESC
0                       undetected
1                       undetected
2                       undetected
3                       undetected
4                       undetected
5                       undetected
6                       undetected
7                       undetected
8                       undetected
9                       undetected
10                      undetected
11                      undetected
12                      undetected
13     TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026
14     TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026
```

**Expected Output in CSV:**

```
SHA-1,VSDT,DESC
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5,MIME 6010-0,TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026
02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324,Microsoft RTF 6008-0,undetected
```

Comment: df1['DESC'] = df['DESC'].values should give you what you need.

Comment: can u give the full answer, so i can vote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of last two lines, replace the below two lines.

df1['DESC'] = df['DESC'].values

df1.to_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",index=False)

Comment: but when i run it again it shows: File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'DESC'

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you confirm both your dataframes df and df1 has the key "DESC" ?